# How to get selected row value in controller when posting mvc form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm binding data table using list. That list I am sending from controller

```
<table id="tblTaskDependency" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Task Name</th>
            <th>Task Description</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.DependencyTaskLsit) {

        <tr>
            <td>@item.TaskName</td>
            <td>@item.TaskDescription</td>

        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and using jQuery binding datatable like below

```
var Dependencytable = $('#tblTaskDependency').DataTable();
```

I am getting the table. Now I need to get selected row data in my controller.

How can I get value of selected row in my controller?

Comment: `Now I need to get selected row data in my controller` <= What does that mean? You created a data table using a jquery plugin on the front end (not same as server side). What is it you are trying to do because the question in itself does not make sense.

Comment: Yes I created  data table using a jquery plugin. But now I want to post my form to controller using object. On the time of post I am getting all data that are bind in model. So how i can get selected row from data table. Is there any idea to do that.